# MyAdapter with setOnClickListener in Activity does work but in Fragment does not work

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

my Adapter with setOnClickListener in Activity does work but in my Fragment does not work.

I have two Adapter with setOnClickListener,both do work in Activity on RecyclerView but None of them don't work in my Fragment's RecyclerView

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        myToolbar.title = "My Test"
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar)

        var myToggle = object :
            ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, myDrawerLayout, myToolbar, 
        R.string.open, R.string.close) {
            override fun onDrawerOpened(drawerView: View) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView)
                invalidateOptionsMenu()
            }

            override fun onDrawerClosed(drawerView: View) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView)
                invalidateOptionsMenu()
            }

             override fun onDrawerSlide(drawerView: View, slideOffset: Float) {
                super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset)
                if (slideOffset < 0.6) {
                    myToolbar.alpha = 1 - slideOffset
                }
            }
        }
        myDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(myToggle)
        myDrawerLayout.post {
            myToggle.syncState()
        }

        var myLinearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        myLinearLayoutManager.orientation = LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL
        var myAdapter = MyAdapter(this, MyDataClass.DataProducer.MyList)

        myRecyclerView.adapter = myAdapter
        myRecyclerView.layoutManager = myLinearLayoutManager

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.myFrameLayoutMain, MainFragment())
            .commit()
    }
}

        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:background="#0068FF"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/myToolbar"
            android:background="#EF30"/>
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/myFrameLayoutMain"
            android:background="#61C224"
            android:layout_below="@id/myToolbar">
        </FrameLayout>
        <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/myDrawerLayout"
            tools:openDrawer="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
            android:layout_below="@id/myToolbar">
         <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/myNavigationView"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:background="#FE7">

                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="My Text in NavigationView"
                        android:textSize="25sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:gravity="center"/>
                <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:background="#EC67">
                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:id="@+id/myRecyclerView"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:background="#000000"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
            </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>




     class MainFragment : Fragment() {
     override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: 
     ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        var view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, 
     false)
        var myRe = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.myRecyclerViewMain)

        var myLinearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        myLinearLayoutManager.orientation = LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL

        var myAdapter = MyAdapterMain(activity, 
     MyDataClass.DataProducer.MyList)
        myRe.adapter = myAdapter
        myRe.layoutManager = myLinearLayoutManager

        return view
    }
    }
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/myRecyclerViewMain"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#9C27B0"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"/>
    </FrameLayout>


    class MyAdapterMain(var context: Context?, var list: List<MyDataClass>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapterMain.MyViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(p0: ViewGroup, p1: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val view: View = 
   LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_pattern_main, p0, false)

        return MyViewHolder(view)

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return list.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(p0: MyViewHolder, p1: Int) {
        p0.myTextHolder.text = MyDataClass.DataProducer.MyList[p1].data
        p0.myCircleImgView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.arezo9696)
        var font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context?.assets, "BYekan.ttf")
        p0.myTextHolder.typeface = font

    }

    inner class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : 
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var myTextHolder = itemView.txtViewPattern!!
        var myCircleImgView = itemView.myCircleImageView!!


        init {
            Log.d("BeForinit MyAdapterMain", "Mahmoud Shokri Test")
            myCircleImgView.setOnClickListener {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Klicked 
    Position\n\t\t\t\t$adapterPosition", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                Log.d("Afterinit MyAdapterMain", "Mahmoud Shokri Test")
            }
        }
    }

    }
    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
    class MyAdapter(var context: Context?, var list: List<MyDataClass>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(p0: ViewGroup, p1: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val view = 
    LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_pattern_nav, p0, false)
        return MyViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return list.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(p0: MyViewHolder, p1: Int) {
        p0.myTextHolder.text = MyDataClass.DataProducer.MyList[p1].data
        p0.myImgHolder.setImageResource(R.drawable.abc_ic_star_black_36dp)
        var font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context?.assets, "BYekan.ttf")
        p0.myTextHolder.typeface = font


    }

    inner class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : 
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var myTextHolder = itemView.txtViewPattern!!
        var myImgHolder = itemView.imgViewPattern!!
        var myRipple = itemView.myRippleView!!


        init {
            Log.d("BeForinit MyAdapterMain", "Mahmoud Shokri Test")
            myRipple.setOnRippleCompleteListener {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Klicked 
        Position\n\t\t\t\t$adapterPosition", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                Log.d("Afterinit MyAdapterMain", "Mahmoud Shokri Test")

            }
        }
     }
     }
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        android:background="#EF7">


        <FrameLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/myCircleImageView"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
                android:layout_width="96dp"
                android:layout_height="96dp"
                app:civ_border_width="2dp"
                app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"
                android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"/>

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:id="@+id/txtViewPattern"
                  android:text="@string/my_test_is_this"
                  android:textSize="30sp"
                  android:textColor="#000000"
                  android:textStyle="bold"
                  android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
                  android:layout_marginStart="5dp"/>
        </FrameLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

For Fragment, init with setOnClickListener(in AdapterMain) is not working.

Answer (score -1):

please change this

```
 var myRe = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.myRecyclerViewMain)
```

to this

```
 var myRe = view.findViewById(R.id.myRecyclerViewMain) as RecyclerView
```